# Are chromosomal microdeletions passed on?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics

I've been looking around but can't find a clear answer: are chromosomal micro-deletions passed on (hereditary) or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Just like any other type of mutation.

If a mutation (incl. a chromosomal microdeletion) happens in the germ line, then the mutation can be passed on.

Comment: another question I may add/ask: if a parent has a chromosomal micro deletion, and uniparental disomy happens, then the child will inherit the deletion as well , right? Thanks for answering

Comment: Yes, necessarily. As both chromosome are passed (uniparental disomy), the one carrying the microdeletion will necessary be passed.

Comment: To be clear, microdeletion is the term for when a gene on one chromosome replaces its counterpart, yes?

Comment: @TheNate I think (but might be wrong) it is a term mainly used in the medical field. I think it refers to a small chromosome deletion (a few kb say) that is too small to be detected by the simple colouring methods (such as FISH or G-banding) often used in medicine.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go start some reading, then.